# How to run Popper on HPC without sudo rights

Tags: hpc, singularity-container, popper

I want to execute a [Popper](https://getpopper.io/) workflow on a Linux HPC (High-performance computing) cluster. I don’t have admin/sudo rights. I know that I should use [Singularity](https://singularity.lbl.gov/) instead of [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) because Singularity is designed to not need `sudo` to run.

However, `singularity build` [needs](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.6/user-guide/build_a_container.html#building-containers-from-singularity-definition-files) `sudo` privileges, if not executed in [fakeroot/rootless](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.6/user-guide/fakeroot.html?highlight=admin) mode.

---

This is what I have done in the HPC login node:

1. I installed [Spack](https://spack.io/) (0.15.4) and Singularity (3.6.1):

```sh
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/spack/spack.git
. spack/share/spack/setup-env.sh
spack install singularity
spack load singularity
```

2. I installed Popper (2.7.0) in a virtual environment:

```sh
python3 -m venv ~/popper
~/popper/bin/pip install popper
```

3. I created an example workflow in `~/test/wf.yml`:

```yaml
steps:
  - uses: "docker://alpine:3.11"
    args: ["echo", "Hello world!"]
  - uses: "./my_image/"
    args: ["Hello number two!"]
```

With `~/test/my_image/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:3.11
ENTRYPOINT ["echo"]
```

4. I tried to run the two steps of the Popper workflow in the login node:

```
$ cd ~/test
$ ~/popper/bin/popper run --engine singularity --file wf.yml 1
[1] singularity pull popper_1_4093d631.sif docker://alpine:3.11
[1] singularity run popper_1_4093d631.sif ['echo', 'Hello world!']
ERROR  : Failed to create user namespace: user namespace disabled
ERROR: Step '1' failed ('1') !

$ ~/popper/bin/popper run --engine singularity --file wf.yml 2
[2] singularity build popper_2_4093d631.sif /home/bikfh/traylor/test/./my_image/
[sudo] password for traylor:
```

So both steps fail.

---

My questions:

- For an image from Docker Hub: How do I enable “user namespace”?
- For a custom image: How do I build an image without `sudo` and run the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For an image from Docker Hub: How do I enable “user namespace”?

I found that the user namespace feature needs to be already enabled on the host machine. [Here](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.5/admin-guide/user_namespace.html#user-namespace-requirements) are instructions for checking whether it’s enabled.

In the case of the cluster computer I am using ([Frankfurt Goethe HLR](https://csc.uni-frankfurt.de/)), user namespaces are only enabled in the computation nodes, *not* the login node.
That’s why it didn’t work for me.

So I need to send the job with SLURM (here only the first step with a container from Docker Hub):

```sh
 ~/popper/bin/popper run --engine singularity --file wf.yml --config popper_config.yml 1
```

`popper_config.yml` defines the [options](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html) for SLURM’s `sbatch` (compare the Popper [docs](https://popper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sections/cn_workflows.html#slurm)). They depend on your cluster computer. In my case it looks like this:

```yml
resource_manager:
  name: slurm
  options:
    "1": # The default step ID is a number and needs quotes here.
      nodes: 1
      mem-per-cpu: 10 # MB
      ntasks: 1
      partition: test
      time: "00:01:00"
```

> For a custom image: How do I build an image without sudo and run the container?

Trying to apply the same procedure to step 2, which has a custom `Dockerfile`, fails with this message:

```
FATAL:   could not use fakeroot: no mapping entry found in /etc/subuid
```

I tried to create the `.sif` file (Singularity image) with Popper on another computer and copy it from `~/.cache/popper/singularity/...` over to the cluster machine.
Unfortunately, Popper seems to clear that cache folder, so the `.sif` image doesn’t persist.

Comment: same here. I am getting the same message.